# json_decode returns NULL, when html entities exist

Tags: php, json

How to use json_decode when json contains html entities? It always returns null.

Here's the  example code:

```
$json = '{
       "text": "&lt;ul&gt;
&lt;li&gt;&lt;strong&gt;&apos;&quot;Example Text&quot;&apos;&lt;/strong&gt;&lt;/li&gt;"
}';

$data = json_decode($json, true);
var_dump($data);
```

Comment: Get rid of the newlines from the JSON part

Answer (score 1):

For some reason you have newlines in the JSON, remove them to make valid JSON and it will decode.

```
$json = '{
    "text": "&lt;ul&gt;
&lt;li&gt;&lt;strong&gt;&apos;&quot;Example Text&quot;&apos;&lt;/strong&gt;&lt;/li&gt;"
}';

//$data = json_decode($json, true);
$data = json_decode( str_replace("\n", '', $json), true );
var_dump($data);
```

RESULT

```
array(1) {
  'text' =>
  string(96) "&lt;ul&gt;&lt;li&gt;&lt;strong&gt;&apos;&quot;Example Text&quot;&apos;&lt;/strong&gt;&lt;/li&gt;"
}
```